# Show Wordpress Posts Associated with Certain Author

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Suppose I want to show posts from one certain author on the main index of a wordpress website, how would I go about this ?? Below is a loop from the twenty thirteen theme:

```
<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['liamhodnett'])) ? get_user_by('liamhodnett', $author) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a>,
        <?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> in <?php the_category('&');?>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

basically, all you need to do is set $curauth

```
<?php
   $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>
```

example for an author page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">

<!-- This sets the $curauth variable -->

    <?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    ?>

    <h2>About: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>Website</dt>
        <dd><a href="<?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?></a></dd>
        <dt>Profile</dt>
        <dd><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></dd>
    </dl>

    <h2>Posts by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>

    <ul>
<!-- The Loop -->

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a>,
            <?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> in <?php the_category('&');?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

<!-- End Loop -->

    </ul>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

**Edit**

I will explain what `$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));` does

`isset($_GET['author_name']) ?` checks whether a parameter with the username is present in the URL, like: www.myexamplewebsite.com/author/danieltulp
[it is a shorthand if/else statement](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

if URL has an username the code will try to get it with `get_user_by('slug', $author_name)`

if it doesn't it will try to get it with the [get_userdata Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function with `get_userdata(intval($author))`

of course, you are not refering to the user in the URL, so you just need to set the currentauth like:

```
$curauth = (is_home()) ? "liamhodnett" : (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
```

---

**Edit 2**
If all else fails (haven't tested the code above, so could very well be possible), make your own database call with [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

```
$args = array(
    'author'        =>  1 // this should be your user ID, or use 'author_name' => 'liamhodnett' 
    );

// get my posts 'ASC'
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Then use the $mypost array for your loop:

```
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DaniëlTulp however it is important that these specific posts are displayed on the main index only, any other suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: if(is_home()){ $curauth = ... } http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: Hi @DaniëlTulp I have edited the loop example above, however I still see posts by all authors on the home page and not just by a single author, in this case 'liamhodnett', have I set the variables right do you think ?? Thanks again

Comment: no, not exactly, I will explain in an edit what the line does

Comment: I can see how this works as far as gathering information like author name, website, biog and other variables detailed in the user profile account. However I can not understand how or why it doesn't show ONLY certain author posts. Perhaps the curauth needs to be IN the loop ?? Thanks again @DaniëlTulp I really appreciate your help and hard work :)